# Cassandra : How to select data updated in last 30 days

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

We have a requirement to load last 30 days updated data from the table.

One of the potential solution below does not allow to do so.

```
select * from XYZ_TABLE where WRITETIME(lastupdated_timestamp) > (TOUNIXTIMESTAMP(now())-42,300,000);

select * from XYZ_TABLE where lastupdated_timestamp > (TOUNIXTIMESTAMP(now())-42,300,000);
```

The table has columns as

```
lastupdated_timestamp (with an index on this field)
lastupdated_userid (with an index on this field)
```

Any pointers ...

Comment: What does your table definition look like?  That's what ultimately determines how your data is sorted, as well as how it can be queried.

Comment: table definition has lastupdated_timestamp (with an index on this field).

Comment: Sam's answer is spot-on.  If you want to be able to query the last 30 days of updated data, you need to *build your table* to support that query from the beginning.

Comment: Agree, Sams solution is good if I am creating a new table design, but here I am extending this table as part of extension of design with maintaining current primary keys (partition and clustered keys) based on business need.

Comment: if possible consider putting a search engine in-front. Like solar or elastic search. That will be your best bet for flexibility (for now and in future).

Another solution will be running a data pipeline to keep the "updated in last 30 days" records (or ids) in a separate db, then use that to get the result that you need.

Answer (score 7):

Unless your table was built with this query in mind, your query will search every partition of the database, which will become very costly once your dataset has become large and will probably result in a timeout.

To efficiently complete this query, the XYZ_TABLE should have a primary key something like so:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((update_month, update_day), lastupdated_timestamp)
```

This is so Cassandra knows right where to go find the data. It has month and day buckets it can quickly find, then you can run queries like this to find updates on a certain day.

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ_TABLE WHERE update_month = 07-18 and update_day = 06
```

Comment: Sam, This solution is good if I am creating a new table design, but here I am extending this table as part of extension of design with maintaining current primary keys (partition and clustered keys) based on business need. Can I query lastupdated_timestamp with index on that ?